# Custom Closable Tab in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to implement a custom closable tab header in kivy.

What I did was combine a class:TabbedPanelHeader object with a custom class:CloseButton object. Both of these widgets are inside a class:BoxLayout, side-by-side.

However, once I add this into a class:TabbedPanel object, nothing shows up..
I am not sure how to move forward and would greatly appreciate all the help!

Below is the relevant part of the code.

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelHeader

class CloseButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CloseButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/close'
        self.size_hint_x = .2

    def on_press(self):
        self.source = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_radio_off'

    def on_release(self):
        self.source = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_radio_off'
        ## do the actual closing of the tab

class ClosableTabHeader(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ClosableTabHeader, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (100, 30)
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.canvas.before.add(Color(.25, .25, .25))
        self.canvas.before.add(Rectangle(size=(105, 30)))
        self.add_widget(TabbedPanelHeader(background_color=(.65, .65, .65, 0), text='testing'))
        self.add_widget(CloseButton())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.app import App

    class TestApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return ClosableTabHeader()

    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Here is some code which comes close to achieve what you are trying to achieve

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelHeader
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.lang import Builder


class CloseableHeader(TabbedPanelHeader):
    pass

class TestTabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string('''
TabbedPanel:
    do_default_tab: False
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            id: tab_1_content
            Label:
                text: 'Palim 1'
        BoxLayout:
            id: tab_2_content
            Label:
                text: 'Palim 2'
        BoxLayout:
            id: tab_3_content
            Label:
                text: 'Palim 3'


    CloseableHeader:
        text: 'tab1'
        panel: root
        content: tab_1_content.__self__
    CloseableHeader:
        text: 'tab2'
        panel: root
        content: tab_2_content.__self__
    CloseableHeader:
        text: 'tab3'
        panel: root
        content: tab_3_content.__self__


<CloseableHeader>
    color: 0,0,0,0
    disabled_color: self.color
    # variable tab_width
    text: 'tabx'
    size_hint_x: None
    width: self.texture_size[0] + 40
    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.size
        padding: 3
        Label:
            id: lbl
            text: root.text
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: None, 1
            orientation: 'vertical'
            width: 22
            Image:
                source: 'tools/theming/defaulttheme/close.png'
                on_touch_down:
                    if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos) :\
                        root.panel.remove_widget(root); \

''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestTabApp().run()
```

It is based on https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/tabbed_panel_showcase.py

Comment: Is there anyway it can be written in Python rather than KV language. I loosely based my code on that script you linked me to. However, I have yet to fully understand KV lang thus why my code doesnt fully work =)

Comment: sure everything you can do in kv you can also do in python. But it is so much more work and kv is really easy. It is worth learning it. I do not want to transfer it to python, I am not even sure if I could. If my question helped or solved your problem please do upvote or accept.

Comment: No problem. Looks like its back to the drawing board for me. Thanks though.